# Copy array to a function c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to know - is there any way to copy array to a function in C/C++? Not pass it just an address, but create a copy... Like for int value. For example here we send not a copy(((:

```
void arrayAbs(int array[], int size) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        if ( array[i] < 0 ) {
            array[i] *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `std::array<T>` ([see reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)), or `std::vector<T>`

Comment: You'll need to write a function to make a copy of your raw array. Otherwise use a `std::vector` or (better) `std::array` (C++11 only)

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ arrays are not copyable. But you can use an array-like standard library container type, such as [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
template <size_t N>
void arrayAbs(std::array<int, N> a) 
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) {
        if ( a[i] < 0 ) {
            a[i] *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `a` is passed by value, so it is a copy of the array passed in by the caller.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for arrays - at least when the size of the array is not known at compile time. Since you are passing `size` as a separate parameter, it appears that a solution with a fixed-size array would not work in your situation.

However, you can use `std::vector<int>` instead. This container will be copied when you pass it by value. As an additional benefit, it knows its size, so passing `int size` would become unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with arrays. Either arrays are converted to pointers to their first elements when passed to a function (in C and C++) or if the parameter is defined as a reference to an array then the reference is passed. in any case neither copy of an array is created.

In C++ you could use standard class `std::array`. in this case you indeed could work with a copy of the original array. In C you could use an analogy of `std::array` in C++ by wrapping an array in a structure.

Comment: Note that OP passes array `size` as a separate parameter. The implication would be that his `arrayAbs` would become generic on the size of the `std::array` passed into it (see Juan's answer).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  it is only details.

Comment: Perhaps that's "only details" to someone with years of experience in C++ and deep knowledge of the Standard C++ Library. However, to a reader who wants to find out if it's possible to pass arrays by value this would not be obvious at all.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Class std:;array is itself a template class. So this details are simply .useless.

Answer (score 0):

In C++: Use `std::array`. In C: Wrap it in a struct.

```c
typedef struct {
    int array[10];
} wrapper;

wrapper function(wrapper wrapped_array) {
    wrapped_array.array[0] = 42;
    return wrapped_array;
}

int main() {
    wrapper wa;
    wrapper wa2 = function(wa);
}
```